# SQL Server looking for .bak in wrong location

Tags: sql-server, restore

I'm trying to restore a database in SQL Server on a new setup (we're in a testing phase moving to an azure Server environment before cutting over). I've used this script in the old location, on SQL Server 2014 and it always worked. The new setup is also using 2014, but when I use this script:

```
RESTORE DATABASE NSW 
FROM DISK = '‪C:\‪C:\Temp\2019_Backups\NSW.bak'
WITH MOVE 'NSW' TO 'C:\SQLData\NSW\NSW.mdf', 
     MOVE 'NSW_log' TO 'C:\SQLData\NSW\NSW.ldf'
```

It throws the following error:

> Msg 3201, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>   Cannot open backup device 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\local\‪C:\Temp\2019_Backups\NSW.bak'. Operating system error 123(The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.).
>
> Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

When I run the following query:

```
SELECT 
    DB_NAME([database_id]) [database_name],
    [file_id],
    [type_desc] [file_type],
    [name] [logical_name],
    [physical_name]
FROM
    sys.[master_files]
WHERE 
    [database_id] = DB_ID('NSW')
ORDER BY 
    [type], DB_NAME([database_id]);
```

I get this:

```
+---------------+---------+-------------------------------------------------------+
| database_name | file_id | file_type | logical_name |        physical_name       |
+---------------+---------+-------------------------------------------------------+
|      NSW      |    1    |    ROWS   |     NSW      |   C:\SQLData\NSW\NSW.mdf   |
+---------------+---------+-------------------------------------------------------+
|      NSW      |    2    |    LOG    |   NSW_log    | C:\SQLData\NSW\NSW_log.ldf |
+---------------+---------+-------------------------------------------------------+
```

How come it's prepending the default backup location even though I'm dictating it in the query? The database was copied to `C:\SQLData\NSW`, that's where it was in the previous environment too (different server, same local address) and it was never, to my knowledge, associated with that default location.

Comment: that is the original location of the database. use `RESTORE FILELISTONLY` to view it. use `RESTORE DATABASE ..  MOVE` option to move to your desire location

Comment: Except that the database files were originally copied to that location too... How would the original location have come to be that?

Comment: @Squirrel I've updated my question with an attempt to do what that comment seemed to be getting at.

Comment: if you do not specify `MOVE` option in `RESTORE`, the original location is used

Comment: where are you executing the `select` query ? the old server ?

Comment: You have the `C:\` twice at the beginning of your `FROM DISK= ` specification - maybe it is just that typo that's causing this behavior?